# Split string by all words except specified words Regex JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a string

```js
const s = 'pong-ping-bink-ping-pong-ping-donk';
```

I want to split it by all words other than `ping` or `pong` with regex.

For this string I expect an array, splitted by `-bink-` and `-donk-`

```js
"pong-ping",
"ping-pong-ping"
```

Another example

```js
const s = 'ping-pong-ping-pong-fong-song-pong-bing';

"ping-pong-ping-pong",
"pong"
```

This is what I am doing now

```js
const s = 'ping-pong-ping-pong-fong-song-pong-bing';

const r = /-(?!ping|?!pong)-/g;
const result = s.split(r);

console.log(result);
```

I'm clearly far from the goal. It returns `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: Nothing to repeat`

What should I do?

Comment: In these cases, it is better to go the other way round, extract what you need: `text.match(/(?<![^-])p[io]ng(?:-p[io]ng)*(?![^-])/g)`. Also, mind the hyphen boundaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex for splitting:

```bash
/(?:-(?!p[io]ng)\w+)+-?/g
```

Then to filter out empty result just use:

```bash
str.split(/(?:-(?!p[io]ng)\w+)+-?/g).filter(Boolean)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/SF1FG3/1)

**Code:**

```js
const rx = /(?:-(?!p[io]ng)\w+)+-?/g;

function splt(s) {
    return s.split(rx).filter(Boolean);
}

const p = 'pong-ping-bink-ping-pong-ping-donk';
console.log(splt(p));

const r = 'ping-pong-ping-pong-fong-song-pong-bing';
console.log(splt(r));
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?:`: Start a non-capture group

  - `-`: Match a `-`
  - `(?!p[io]ng)`: Negative lookahead to assert that we don't have `ping` or `pong` on the rights side of the current position
  - `\w+`: Match 1+ of word characters
- `)+`: Close non-capture group and repeat this group 1+ times
- `-?`: Match `-` optionally

Comment: Maybe it\`s better to use `.pop()` instead of `.filter()`?

Comment: `pop()` will only return last element (empty) from the array.